# How can I loop through a string list to take each word in Python

Tags: python, string, loops

I have this long list of place names (this is an example) 
Monroe Alabama,
Montgomery Alabama,
Morgan  Alabama,
Perry Alabama,
Pickens Alabama,
Pike Alabama,
Randolph Alabama,
Russell Alabama,
Winston Alabama,
Aleutians East Alaska,
Aleutians West  Alaska,
Anchorage Alaska,
Bethel  Alaska,
Bristol Bay Alaska....

I need to iterate over the list so that each placename can be put into this:

location = geolocator.geocode('placename')

How can I do this in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: `places.split(",")`?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is split the string to an actual list, considering comma as a delimiter and then iterate over the actual list.

This could look like

```
string_list = 'Monroe Alabama, Montgomery Alabama, Morgan Alabama, Perry Alabama, Pickens Alabama, Pike Alabama, Randolph Alabama, Russell Alabama, Winston Alabama, Aleutians East Alaska, Aleutians West Alaska, Anchorage Alaska'
actual_list = string_list.split(',')
for word in actual_list:
    print word
    # Do stuff also
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what `split()` function is for.

```
for word in your_list.split(','):
    location = geolocator.geocode(word.strip()) #strip is to remove extra spaces, as Mike mentioned in the comments
```

This will do the trick